# What is the optimal way to create a recombined version of two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I would like to randomly recombine two lists of the following form:

```
l1 = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
l2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Where their recombination is similar to that of DNA, so that there is a random choice between each least at each index of the lists, like in the following:

```
Table[RandomChoice[{l1[[n]], l2[[n]]}], {n, Length[l1]}]
```

that gives:

```
{a, 2, c, 4, e, f}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? And, if so, can it also work on multidimensional lists? Thanks!

Edit (1/2/2020):
I would like to clarify a little what I meant by "multidimensional lists". All of the answers so far are really good for optimizing the speed of operation, however, for multidimensional lists like the following:

```
l1 = {{a,b},{c,d}}; l2 = {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

The result I get is something like:

```
{{a,b},{3,4}}
```

when applied to a multidimensional list, whereas, I am trying to find a way to get something like:

```
{{a,2},{c,4}}
```

or:

```
{{1,b},{c,4}}
```

without having to use Table[] and recursively calling a function to operate on the sub-components, which would be very inefficient. For example, is there simple command to give Thread[] or Map[] that will allow for this multidimensional functionality? Thanks again for the great answers - seeing as how this is a slightly two tiered question, I may just ask a whole new question relating to this edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) is more efficient than [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using longer lists to extend the timing.

```
l1 = CharacterRange["a", "z"] // ToExpression;

l2 = Range[Length[l1]];
```

With [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
SeedRandom[1234]

table = RepeatedTiming[
  Table[RandomChoice[{l1[[n]], l2[[n]]}], {n, Length[l1]}]]

(* {0.0000481, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, 14, o, 16, q, 18, 19, 
  t, 21, v, 23, x, y, z}} *)
```

With [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)

```
SeedRandom[1234]

transpose = RepeatedTiming[RandomChoice /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}]]

(* {0.000026, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 18, 19, t, 
  21, v, 23, x, y, z}} *)
```

With [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
SeedRandom[1234]

thread = RepeatedTiming[RandomChoice /@ Thread[{l1, l2}]]

(* {0.000019, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 18, 19, t, 
  21, v, 23, x, y, z}} *)
```

Comparing the timings:

```
(First /@ {table, transpose, thread})/table[[1]]

{1.00, 0.54, 0.39}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a lot faster than the original. Is there a quick way to make this multidimensional so that if I had {{a,b},{c,d}} and {{1,2},{3,4}}, I could get a result like {{1,b},{3,d}} or {{a,2},{3,d}}, as a random choice?

Comment: @Jmeeks29ig - Perhaps `Map[RandomChoice, Thread[{l1, l2}], {2}]` If not, recommend that you ask a new question and provide more detail about what you are looking for in the multidimensional case.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out and see how it works, and just create another question if it's going to be something more involved. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 12):

I would do it like this

```
RandomChoice /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely faster, by about 14% with Timing[].

Comment: `ParallelMap` might be even faster for large lists

Answer (score 1):

For large inputs using a binary mask generated with `RandomInteger` is faster than posted alternatives:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

recomb1 = Module[{la = #, lb = #2,
   pos = Flatten[SparseArray[RandomInteger[1, Dimensions@#]]["NonzeroPositions"]]}, 
  la[[pos]] = lb[[pos]]; la] &;

recomb2 = Module[{pos = Random`Private`PositionsOf[RandomInteger[1, Length@#], 1], 
     la = #, lb = #2}, la[[pos]] = lb[[pos]]; la] &;

recomb3 = Module[{, la = Flatten@#, lb = Flatten@#2,
    pos = Random`Private`PositionsOf[RandomInteger[1, Times @@ Dimensions[#]], 1]}, 
   la[[pos]] = lb[[pos]]; ArrayReshape[la, Dimensions@#]] &;

recomb4 = Module[{pos = RandomInteger[1, Dimensions@#]}, (1 - pos) # + pos #2] &;
```

Using `l1` and `l2` from Bob Hanlon's post:

```
l1 = CharacterRange["a", "z"] // ToExpression;
l2 = Range[Length[l1]];

SeedRandom[1234]
RepeatedTiming[res1 = recomb1[l1, l2]]
```

> {0.000028, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 18,
>          19, t, 21, v, 23, x, y, z}}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
RepeatedTiming[res2 = recomb2[l1, l2]]
```

> {0.000019, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 18,
>          19, t, 21, v, 23, x, y, z}}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
RepeatedTiming[res3 = recomb3[l1, l2]]
```

> {0.0000386, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 
>         18, 19, t, 21, v, 23, x, y, z}}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
RepeatedTiming[res4 = recomb4[l1, l2]]
```

> {0.000031, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 18,
>          19, t, 21, v, 23, x, y, z}}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
RepeatedTiming[res5 = RandomChoice /@ Thread[{l1, l2}]]
```

> {0.000025, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 18,
>          19, t, 21, v, 23, x, y, z}}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
RepeatedTiming[res6 = RandomChoice /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}]]
```

> {0.000036, {1, 2, 3, d, e, f, g, h, i, 10, 11, l, 13, n, o, 16, q, 18,
>      19, t, 21, v, 23, x, y, z}}

***Multi-dimensional inputs:***

`recomb3` and `recomb4` can handle multi-dimensional lists:

```
l1 = ArrayReshape[CharacterRange["a", "z"] // ToExpression, {13, 2}]
```

> {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, j}, {k, l}, {m, n}, {o, p}, {q, 
>     r}, {s, t}, {u, v}, {w, x}, {y, z}}

```
l2 = ArrayReshape[Range[Length[l1]], {13, 2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {13, 14}, {15, 
>     16}, {17, 18}, {19, 20}, {21, 22}, {23, 24}, {25, 26}}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
recomb3[l1, l2]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, 10}, {11, l}, {13, n}, {o, 
>     16}, {q, 18}, {19, t}, {21, v}, {23, x}, {y, z}}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
recomb4[l1, l2]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {i, 10}, {11, l}, {13, n}, {o, 
>     16}, {q, 18}, {19, t}, {21, v}, {23, x}, {y, z}}

**Timings for large inputs:**

***Symbolic `l1`:***

```
n = 1000000;
SeedRandom[1234]
l1 = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"] // ToExpression, n];
l2 = Range[Length[l1]];

SeedRandom[1234]
First @ RepeatedTiming[res1 = recomb1[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.15

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First @ RepeatedTiming[res2 = recomb2[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.13

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First@RepeatedTiming[res3 = recomb3[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.15

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First @ RepeatedTiming[res4 = recomb4[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.77

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First @ RepeatedTiming[res5 = RandomChoice /@ Thread[{l1, l2}];]
```

> 0.93551

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First @ RepeatedTiming[res6 = RandomChoice /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}];]
```

> 1.11

***Integer `l1`:***

```
SeedRandom[1234]
n = 1000000;
l1 = n + ArrayComponents @ RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"] // ToExpression, n];
l2 = Range[Length[l1]];

SeedRandom[1234]
First@RepeatedTiming[res1 = recomb1[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.054

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First@RepeatedTiming[res2 = recomb2[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.043

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First@RepeatedTiming[res3 = recomb3[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.050

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First@RepeatedTiming[res4 = recomb4[l1, l2];]
```

> 0.035

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First@RepeatedTiming[res5 = RandomChoice /@ Thread[{l1, l2}];]
```

> 0.53

```
SeedRandom[1234]
First@RepeatedTiming[res6 = RandomChoice /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}];]
```

> 0.205

Answer (score 1):

For your general case, you can capture the structure of `l1` and `l2`, flatten them out and do the merge, then re-structure them using `ArrayReshape`. In fact, we'll use `ArrayReshape` to create the test data in the first place.

```
l3 = ArrayReshape[Range[12], {2, 3, 2}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}} *)

l4 = ArrayReshape[CharacterRange[101, 112], {2, 3, 2}]
(* {{{"e", "f"}, {"g", "h"}, {"i", "j"}}, {{"k", "l"}, {"m", "n"}, {"o", "p"}}} *)
```

Grab the dimensions, note it is the same as the second argument in `ArrayReshape`.

```
structure = Dimensions@l3
(* {2, 3, 2} *)
```

Flatten and get those results using method du jour from @Bob, then reshape it all.

```
flattenedResult = RandomChoice /@ Thread[Flatten /@ {l3, l4}]
(* {"e", "f", 3, "h", 5, 6, 7, "l", 9, "n", 11, 12} *)

finalRes = ArrayReshape[flattenedResult, structure]
(* {{{"e", "f"}, {3, "h"}, {5, 6}}, {{7, "l"}, {9, "n"}, {11, 12}}} *)
```

Didn't do a timing check.